# altering property sheet of files

Tags: c#, c++, .net

How is it possible to alter the property dialog of a file we see when we take right click and select properties, i want to insert my own property sheet there and read/set values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a C++ question. You may want to check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144106(v=vs.85).aspx